# UIPageViewController with tableview

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview, uipageviewcontroller

I made three VC:

1. Content VC "Image" 0 to all dimensions "full"
2. VC  "tableview" 0 to all dimensions "full"
3. Page Controller VC

**I want the VC to be like the image below "the image top 60% and tableview bottom 40%"** Do I have to make the tableview and image in one ViewController or separate?

This is the code "I got lost in CGRectMake" tableview showed up in top!

```
self.pageViewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 110, self.view.frame.width, self.view.frame.height - 300)

self.addChildViewController(self.pageViewController)
self.view.addSubview(self.pageViewController.view)
self.pageViewController.didMoveToParentViewController(self)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use a regular `UIViewController` to hold the tableView and the image.

It would look something like:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let imageViewFrame = CGRect(origin: CGPointZero, size: CGSize(width: view.frame.width, height:view.frame.height * 0.6) )
    let imageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "YOUR_IMAGE_NAME"))
    imageView.frame = imageViewFrame
    view.addSubview(imageView)

    let tableView = ... //create the tableview, set its delegate/datasource
    let tableViewOrigin: CGPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: view.frame.height * 0.6)
    let tableViewSize = CGSize(width: view.frame.width, height: view.frame.height * 0.4)
    tableView.frame = CGRect(origin: tableViewOrigin, size: tableViewSize) 
    view.addSubview(tableView)   
}
```

Then add this VC to your pageViewController

Comment: I did it manaully it works fine one thing that that app crash after implementing tableview datasource and delegate ? thats weird

Comment: please take look at the project https://www.dropbox.com/s/y9vspdvsu1biit8/Archive.zip?dl=0

Comment: I took a look. The app didn't crash for me but I did need to change a line in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. I changed `let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath)` to `let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell`

Comment: it crashes after assigning tableview delegate and datasource

Comment: error pointed at self.tabelview.datasource  = self & delegate :: error msg fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Comment: I added both at VC not the "content viewcontroller "